# Prevent user from submitting more than one review for a product

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In my current system a user can write a review for a  product.

Below is the method where the validation and creation of the review takes place in my Controller:

```
public function PostAndValidate($id)
{
    $input = [
        'comment' => Input::get('comment'),
        'rating'  => Input::get('rating')
    ];
    $review = new Review;
    $validator = Validator::make( $input, $review->getCreateRules());
  return to product page with error message
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $review->storeReviewForBook($id, $input['comment'], $input['rating']);
        return Redirect::to('book/'.$id.'#reviews-anchor')->with('review_posted',true);
    }

    return Redirect::to('book/'.$id.'#reviews-anchor')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

**How can I prevent the user to post a new review for a book or product where he or she already reviewed?**

Comment: can you show the database structure for review, books, and users?

Comment: the database structure  up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following in your `storeReviewForBook` method:

```
$book = Book::find($id);

if(in_array(Auth::user()->id, $book->reviews->lists('user_id')->all())) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'You already reviewed this book');
}
```

Comment: i dont think you need the ->all() after lists.

Comment: It was introduced in 5.1. Unless it was reverted in 5.2. Doesn't seem to be in the docs.

Comment: I also don't think this would work because storeReviewForBook is in the model and returning from that scope won't affect the script running in the controller. he should do the validating in the controller.

Comment: You are right, it must be in the controller.

Comment: I borrowed your validation cause its very clean. hope you don't mind.

Comment: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

Comment: Please do the following, `dd(Book::find($id)->reviews->lists('user_id')->all()` and show me the output.

Comment: @Gokigooooks not at all.

Comment: I forgot this shows an error if the return from list is empty.. ill change my code

Comment: it worked but with out message 'You already reviewed this book'

Comment: worked thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

First off as a good habit, as much as possible put all your logic in the controllers. you dont need a storeReviewForBook in your Review model file.

I would write your postAndValidate function like so,

```
public function PostAndValidate($id)
{
    $input = [
        'comment' => Input::get('comment'),
        'rating'  => Input::get('rating')
    ];

    $review = new Review;
    $validator = Validator::make( $input, $review->getCreateRules());

    if ($validator->passes()) {

        //queries for a review with book id and user id matching the current transaction
        $existing = Review::where('book_id','=',$id)
                         ->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
                         ->first();
        //last query returns null if nothing is returned
        if($existing!=null) 
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'You already reviewed this book');
        }
        else
        {  

            $review->comment = $input['comment'];
            $review->rating = $input['rating'];
            $review->book_id = $id;
            $review->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $review->save();

            return Redirect::to('book/'.$id.'#reviews-anchor')->with('review_posted',true);
        }


    return Redirect::to('book/'.$id.'#reviews-anchor')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

The model should be the layer to interact with the database while you place your logic in the controller. its also more readable and easier to debug.

**EDIT**
As a form of data integrity you could put a unique index in the user_id and the book_id in the reviews table. place user_id and book_id as an array so the unique index will be of the 2 columns combined.

```
//in migration file
$table->unique(['user_id','book_id']);
```

Comment: i got this error in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

Comment: i got this error  --   Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: can you change count to count() see my edit

Comment: please see my last edit